# Where does business logic in a model method go in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models that are related to each other with one-to-many relationships.

- Model A can have many instances of Model B.
- Model A can have many instances of Model C.
- Model B can have many instances of Model C.

The idea is that a user would create an instance of Model A (like a stock portfolio) and then enter stock holdings (Model C). Where Model B fits in is that I want to run calculations/logic based on the stocks (Model C) in the portfolio (Model A) and using another class/model to keep track of things makes life easier, hence Model B.

I originally had the logic for these calculations in a Django view but read in *Two Scoops of Django* that business logic should be separated from views. As a result I moved the logic to a method of Model A (the portfolio) and now call that method from a view. This logic loops through the stock holdings and creates new instances of Model B, the results.

I am now interested in exploring django-rest-framework to provide an API to a javascript frontend (like Angular). I am guessing that I will not be able to have this kind of data manipulation within my REST interfaces. However, the result of this logic (data in Model B) needs to be visible via REST. Therefore, where does this type of calculation/logic go?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Django Rest Framework main pieces are views (ViewSets, ApiViews, etc) and serializers. Neither of those are ideal places to write logic.
As you mentioned, writing logic in any view is not good. Why?

1. No way to use the same logic from another part of the app
2. No way to encapsulate the logic (you need to call the view for the
   logic to run)
3. No way to unit test the logic because is coupled with the view

IMHO, models are not a good place to write logic. Think of a model as your database definition. I would keep them as simple as possible. You can override "save" and other methods to do trivial tasks. Any other advanced functionality should live outside of it.

I can think of two better places for what you need:

One of them is a [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/)

A better one is a custom class.
Encapsulate/decouple the logic in your own class (you can use static or instance methods, it doesn´t matter), and then you will be able to:

1. Unit test those methods / mock that class
2. Reuse this logic somewhere else
3. Simplify your code according to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle
4. Use it from a signal keeping the signal code simple
5. Use it from a celery task (if you implement this in the future) without modifying a single line of your code

**UPDATE** An example of how to organize the code.

> From the comments it´s clear that a signal wouldn´t work because the analysis operation will run on user request. A signal would be useful if that operation should run automatically when saving an specific model.
>
> I´m assuming you know how to use django-rest-framework api views or
> viewsets, serializers, etc. I you don´t how about that, better ask
> another question. This is going to be more a python explanation than anything else

In your app module, create a file `app_business_logic.py`or whatever you want to call it. You can place it at the same level of the models.py for instance, but it´s not mandatory:

```
class HoldingsAnalyser:
    # static method sample. Call it like this: "HoldingsAnalyser.run(..)"
    @staticmethod
    def run(holding_list):
        # do your model generation here or whatever you need
        return True # or whatever you need to return

    # instance method sample. Create an instance first and then call the method: 
    # analyser = HoldingsAnalyser()
    # analyser.run(...)
    def run(self, holding_list):
        # do your model generation here or whatever you need
        return True # or whatever you need to return
```

Now, in a django-rest-framework api view or viewset, create a POST method to be called when the client app user press the button (that button to generate analysis):

```
from yourapp.app_business_logic import HoldingsAnalyser

class StockPortfolioViewSet(WhatEverMixingYouNeedToInheritFrom):
    serializer_class = whatever # look at the docs
    
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def run_analysis(self, request, pk):
        stock_portfolio = get the object based on the pk
        holdings = make your query to get the holdings
        analysis_result = HoldingsAnalyser.run(holdings)
        if analysis_result:
            # everything ok
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        else:
            return Response(a useful error for your client)
```

The url for this would be something like `http://server.com/api_path/stockportfolio/21/run_analysis/`, where 21 would be the id of the StockPortfolio

Comment: Thanks @xleon for the response. I am still unsure of where all of this (signals or custom classes) fits into a project. 

I am envisioning a user will be looking at their holdings (Model C) in their portfolio (Model A). They will then be able to run the analysis (looping through each holding and creating Model B instances) by clicking an 'analyze' button. Ultimately, all 3 models would be available via a REST API. If the user hasn't run the analysis then the API for Model B would be empty. If the analysis logic is in a signal or custom class when is it called to populate the Model B API?

Comment: If you run the analysis through a user action, a django signal is not an option (only recommended if that analysis should run automatically when saving other model). I´ll update the answer with some pseudo code for your workflow

Comment: Wow. Excellent example. I always wondered about placing business logic in models.py. Some popular publications suggest that is the place to put it, but I have always had my doubts.

Comment: That´s true, many django expert devs suggest models.py as the place to put that logic. I just don´t get it

Comment: This is a good answer, after creating a few projects in django, I've realised that models are the place where database specific logic should be placed while custom classes should be created for your business logic. The business logic class can always use the model class methods to implement its logic. This provides a separation of concerns. Django docs and everywhere else they advise to put it in models.py, but I believe thats for db specific logic , not business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with where to put business logic for a bit. I agree, models should be thin. So should views.

In one project I had a `services.py` file with thousands of lines of functions that handled all my logic. Honestly, it was totally fine.

Currently, I make helper classes which I call suffix with "Logic". Often these map 1:1 with models (for example I might have a `Holdings` model and `Portofolio` model. And then I would create a `HoldingsLogic` or `PortfolioLogic` to deal with stuff in those models. Sometimes things operate across models... Maybe you need `PortfolioMetrcsLogic` which operates on multiple models.

Not sure if this is gonna be better than my huge `services.py` file in a previous project but signs are pointing to yes. :)